# save and retrieve values within web app

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple web app built in asp.net webforms c#

where and how would be the best way to save info from the code behind?
(and also retrieve that info)

eg all i want to save is a dateTime. and a flag set to True or False.
and be able to access them in the code behind.

Im not using a db for this web app.

Edit: and can't really use session variables for this purpose.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to read the saved variable after a lengthy period of time, you should store it in a local file or a database.

You can create a file using a `FileStream` object and then write your value to the file.

To get a path where your application has sufficient rights to write a file, use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx).

Note : If possible, and if the data you store should not be available to users, you should configure your IIS WebSite to forbid him to serve this file to clients.

Answer (score 3):

If you have to save data for an arbitrary period of time, then you need to store it in a database.

Comment: how about updating an appsetting in web.config?

Answer (score 1):

Use Application variable like Application["thedate"] = date; and you can get back as date = Application["thedate"].
The date will be saved untill app pool restarts (which also happens when IIS or system restarts).

For a more longer time, save in an xml file on the disk (Use XMLReader and XMLWriter for this purpose).

Answer (score 1):

If this is per user info you could use either browser cookie or viewstate.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Session object:

```
Session["thedate"] = date;

DateTime date = (DateTime)Session["thedate"];
```

Comment: sorry, should have mentioned, I dont want to use session variables. The app may save and then later retrieve after lengthy periods of time. I dont want it to fail with sessions expiring etc... so something more permanent.